# Stream IncomingMessage audio data as it's coming in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, playback, audio-player

I'm trying to use the [speaker](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-speaker#readme) module to stream audio from a web request, returning an unending stream of audio data in Buffer form to my speakers.
So I'm trying to use the `res.on('data', . . .)` event to do something with the chunks, but I just can't seem to figure out what to do.

I've thought of something along those lines:

```js
const https = require('https');
const Speaker = require('speaker');

var speaker = new Speaker({
    channels: 2,
    bitDepth: 16,
    sampleRate: 44100
});

https.get('<url>', (res) => {
    res.on('data', chunk => {
        /* Somehow convert the Buffer to PCM audio data and 
         * give it to the speaker
         */
    });
});
```

I've been googling and trying for 2 days, and figured I'd ask here now.

Answer (score 0):

The `res` object you get in callback is a stream, and the speaker instance you created is a writable stream ([from docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speaker#:%7E:text=Writable%20stream%20instance)) , so you can just simply pipe them together. Some thing like this :

```
// Not tested code.
const https = require('https');
const Speaker = require('speaker');

let speaker = new Speaker({
    channels: 2,
    bitDepth: 16,
    sampleRate: 44100
});

https.get('<url>', (res) => {
    res.pipe(speaker);
});
```